# LogIn UWP C# + MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, c#, mysql, login, uwp

Hola de nuevo muchachos;

¿Cómo puedo consumir un servicio web PHP desde una aplicación universal en C#?

He buscado por ahi muchos códigos hasta que encontré este de [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx) que funciona muy bien, todo está en el MainPage.cs.

Lo que intento es crear una clase independiente que consuma el servicio web y que devuelva una cadena JSON, además que se muestre un progress circular mientras se espera a que termine el proceso.

Les dejo el código:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int contentLength = await AccessTheWebAsync();

            resultsTextBox.Text +=
                String.Format("\r\nLength of the downloaded string: {0}.\r\n", contentLength);
        }


        async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
        { 
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
            DoIndependentWork();
            string urlContents = await getStringTask;
            return urlContents.Length;
        }
        void DoIndependentWork()
        {
            resultsTextBox.Text += "Working . . . . . . .\r\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¡Qué bueno que compartas tus soluciones! De todos modos, recomiendo darle a [edit] para proporcionar un enunciado claro que defina qué quieres hacer, de acuerdo con lo indicado en [ask]. De lo contrario, la tupla pregunta-respuesta queda un poco coja en la parte de la pregunta. Se está comentando en Meta: [Usar StackOverflow como blog técnico](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/83)

Comment: A mi no me queda claro cuál es el problema y por lo tanto, que se supone que resuelve la respuesta. Propongo la pregunta para cierre, en espera que se subsanen las omisiones referidas.

Comment: @toledano Lo que ha compartido el usuario Jorny es la manera de cómo usar un servicio en PHP con MySQL y consumirlo desde una aplicación universal de windows (UWP) mediante C#.

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por iluminar a nuestro hermano @ toledano

Comment: @fredyfx Supongo que le di demasías vueltas al asunto. El OP no expone un problema concreto de programación. No aporta un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable que permita reproducir el problema que resuelve con su respuesta. La pregunta con carencias y la respuesta sin comentarios, son una mala combinación.

Comment: @toledano ya actualice mi pregunta que os parece ahora

Comment: @toledano si lo vemos separado, comparto la misma idea. En lo personal, entendí al ver la pregunta y auto-respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí la solución:

1. Cree una clase que realiza el consumo al servicio web de forma asyncrona y devuelve una cadena JSON.
2. En el MainPage se captura esa cadena JSON y se parsea para leer las secciones del JSON.
3. Se muestra un progreso circular mientras el proceso no termina.
4. Lo único que faltaría implementar sería que la App se "bloquee" hasta que el proceso termine.
5. Aquí el código completo.

**MAINPAGE.XAML**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Usuario:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtUsu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,23,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="jorny83@gmail.com" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,67,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Contraseña" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="txtPass" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" Password="12" />
    <Button x:Name="btnSesion" Content="Iniciar sesión" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" Click="ClickSesion"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblResultado" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="10,199,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Resultado" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="302"/>

    <ProgressRing x:Name="pbRing" IsActive="False" Height="48" Width="48" />
</Grid>
```

**MAINPAGE.XAML.CS**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Data.Json;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace LoginPHP {
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page    {
        zClsHTTP clsPHP;
        public MainPage()        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            clsPHP = new zClsHTTP();
        }

        private async void ClickSesion(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            /*variables para almacenar secciones de JSON*/
            string CadenaJSON;
            string sCat = "", sMen = "";
            string sApe = "", sNom = "";

            CadenaJSON = await IniciarSesion();

            /*Crear objeto Json parseando CadenaJson, si alguna sección contiene un JSon Interno, este se convertirá en object*/
            JsonObject objJson = JsonObject.Parse(CadenaJSON);
            /*leer secciones del Json que son un string simple*/
            sCat = objJson["CAT"].GetString();
            sMen = objJson["MEN"].GetString();

            if (sCat.Equals("ERROR"))   {
                /*Mostrar mensaje de error*/
                lblResultado.Text = "El usuario no existe.";
            } else if(sCat.Equals("CORRECTO"))   {
                switch (sMen)                 {
                    case "INGRESAR":
                        /*Obtener secciones del JSON interno de la sección DAT, recordemos que este es un object, 
                         * por ello se usa GetObject*/
                        sApe = objJson["DAT"].GetObject().GetNamedString("APELLIDOS");
                        sNom = objJson["DAT"].GetObject().GetNamedString("NOMBRES");
                        /*Mostrar mensaje de bienvenida*/
                        lblResultado.Text = "Bienvenido " + sApe + " " + sNom;
                        break;
                }
            }
            /*ocultar progreso circular*/
            pbRing.IsActive = false;
        }

        async Task<string> IniciarSesion() {
            /*url del archivo php que recibe la peticion*/
            string url = "http://www.sitio.com/loguear.php";
            /* proceso que muestra el progreso circular mientras se espera a que la peticion devuelva un resultado*/
            Progreso();
            /*esperando respuesta*/
            string JsonPHP = await clsPHP.ConectaWeb(url, txtUsu.Text, txtPass.Password);
            /*devolver resultados*/
            return JsonPHP.ToString();
        }
        void Progreso() {
            /*mostrar progreso circular*/
            pbRing.IsActive = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**zClsHTTP.CS**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LoginPHP {
    /*Clase que permite realizar peticiones Asíncronas a una página PHP a través de HTTP Client y que devuelve una cadena JSON*/
    class zClsHTTP {
        /*Método asincrono que recibe n parámetros de tipo string*/
        public async Task<string> ConectaWeb(params string[] datos)   {
            /*crear diccionario para almacenar parámetros indicados*/
            var valores = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            /*agregar a diccionario cada valor utilizando un modelo (ENV*) el cual será recibido por la página PHP,
             aquí no se envía datos[0] porque este tiene URL de la pagina PHP*/
            for (int i = 1; i < datos.Length; i++) {
                valores.Add("ENV" + i.ToString(), datos[i].ToString());
            }
            /*Crear un formulario con los valores del diccionario*/
            var formulario = new FormUrlEncodedContent(valores);
            /*crear cliente para conectar a la web*/
            HttpClient Conexion = new HttpClient();
            /*enviar el formulario con método POST, al URL que está en datos[0] y esperar respuesta*/
            var respuesta = await Conexion.PostAsync(datos[0].ToString(), formulario);
            /*Leer contenido de respuesta devuelta por la pagina PHP*/
            Task<string> contenido = respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string JsonPHP = await contenido;
            /*Reemplazar comillas simples por dobles, esto es exigencia de C#*/
            string JsonSharp = JsonPHP.Replace("'", "\"");
            return JsonSharp.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**EL PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['ENV1']) and isset($_POST['ENV2'])){
        $sUsuar = $_POST['ENV1'];
        $sClave = $_POST['ENV2'];

        /*consulta SQL para verificiar login y su respectiva 
        verificion bla bla bla*/

        /*si el login es correcto envio un JSON de CORRECTO y los datos del usuario en la base de datos*/
        echo "{'CAT':'CORRECTO','MEN':'INGRESAR','DAT':{'APELLIDOS':'$sApes','NOMBRES':'$sNoms'}}";
        /*si es incorrecto, envio un JSON de Error*/
        echo "{'CAT':'ERROR','MEN':'NADA','DAT':'NADA'}";
    }
?>
```

Comment: gracias bro :D te sugiero que hagas un blog y lo publiques ahí también! éxitos y sigue así! con todo el power!

Comment: gracias @fredyfx ahora que lo sugieres lo estoy pensando jejeje ;)

Comment: de nada hermano, cuando lo tengas, lo posteas aquí: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1203/vamos-difundiendo-nuestros-blogs-entre-la-hermandad-de-soes :D sigue viendo cómo mejorar la calidad de preguntas y respuestas para darle un mayor aporte a la comunidad :D Saludos